# What is the best way using BQL to select non-duplicate items from BQL?

Tags: erp, acumatica

What is the best way using BQL to select non-duplicate items from BQL?

```
Search<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, 
 Where<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, IsNotNull>,
    And<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, ***not already in results***>>?
```

Current Results:
52-55555555555
52-55555555555   <-- remove this duplicate
52-12345678
52-144550099

Results should be :
52-55555555555
52-12345678
52-144550099

Comment: found my own answer:

Search4<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, Where<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, IsNotNull>, Aggregate<GroupBy<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr>>>

Comment: Using the Aggregate and GroupBy solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Aggregate and GroupBy constructs gave the desired results.

found my own answer:

```
  Search4<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, 
    Where<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr, IsNotNull>, 
Aggregate<GroupBy<PRTaxCode.prGovtRefNbr>>>
```